# Changing div _rmc values

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

In my div TAG there is a **_rmc** value.
well inside there is a variable called **PreferValueIndex** i need to change that value to one of the options (1, -1, -9999) 1 = true , -1 false , -9999 block.
i need some help on how to do this . and an explanation about what is _rmc means.

using:

```
import logging
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Well that `_rmc` looks like a attribute to me. Can you share xpath or any other locator for that div ?

Comment: First of all Rob thanks for the note, secondly cruise there is the xpath /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the attribute like this  :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('_rmc','your new value')", element)
```

Where `element` is the webelement (the div )

**Update :**

```
value = "relative; background-color: rgb(215, 14, 82); cursor: url(""Images/cant.cur"")"
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('_rmc','{value}')", element)
```

Comment: ill give it a try

Comment: arguemets[0] means ?

Comment: the `element` that you are passing in the `execute_script`,  it will be treated as `arguments[0]`

Comment: that is the xpath of the div /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]")` - pass this in place of `element`

Comment: that worked but what if inside 'your new  value' i got more ()[]"'" operators how the syntax work there , for example i got this                                                                 
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','position: relative; background-color: rgb(215, 14, 82); cursor: url('Images/cant.cur'), default;')", element)

Comment: you can make a variable, let's say `value = "relative; background-color: rgb(215, 14, 82); cursor: url("Images/cant.cur")"` and then, you can pass this variable as `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('_rmc','{value}')", element)`

Comment: updated above as well

Comment: the "" in the url ( ) i changed to ' ' but still got an error .  ERROR : javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: How are passing this element ? or what value ?

Comment: I need to see your entire code lines that are causing the failure and please share the entire stack trace

Comment: Problem solved i edited your code above. Thanks !!